# Problems doing the Rosenblatt's perceptron in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

I need to implements the Rosenblatt's perceptron in Python3.

The algorithm is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDJgk.jpg

I want to have a funtion that implements the algorithm, the inputs should be the X and Y matrices for the problem to be solved, and the output should be the w vector.

In this case the w vector is composed by the bias and weights.

Here, the matrix X and Y

```py
X_and = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]])
Y_and = np.array([[0], [0], [0], [1]])
X_or = X_and.copy()  
Y_or = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [1]])
print(X_and)
print(Y_and)
print(X_or)
print(Y_or)
```

```
[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 1]]
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]
[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 1]]
[[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

Here, the code that I did

```py
def perceptron_learn(x, y):
    w=np.zeros(3)
    error=True
    while error==True:
        i=0
        error= False
        while i < len(y):
            o = x[i]*(w)
            if np.any(o != y[i]):
                w = w + (y[i]-o)*(x[i])
                error = True
            i=i+1
    return w, i
```

Now, I'am having an error with a infinity loop.

The help will be appreciated!!

Comment: your `o` has 3 elements and `y[i]` has only 1, and I don't think using np.any to compare them is what you need. am I missing something...?

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your help. And how many elements should have? Now I have 2 options. One with ```o = x[i]*(w)``` and the other is ```o = x[i].dot(w)``` with the second I have only 1 element in o.